# Spring framework customize ServiceLocatorFactoryBean with complex type

Tags: java, spring, service-locator, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to customize the way we use service locator pattern to have more complex type

```
@Configuration
public class VehicleConfig {
    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<?> factoryBean() {
        final ServiceLocatorFactoryBean bean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceLocatorInterface(ServiceRegistry.class);
        return bean;
    }
}

public interface AdapterService<T> {
    public void process(T request);
}
public interface ServiceRegistry {
    public <T> AdapterService<T> getService(String serviceName);
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/vehicle")
public class VehicleController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    @PostMapping
    public void processStudentDetails(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
        serviceRegistry.getService(vehicle.getVehicleType()).process(vehicle);
    }
}
@Service("Bike")
public class BikeService implements AdapterService<Vehicle> {

    @Override
    public void process(Vehicle request) {
        System.out.println("inside bike service - " + request.toString());
    }
}

public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

    private String vehicleName;
    private String vehicleType;
}
```

In the above code i want to have more complex vehicle type

```
serviceRegistry.getService(vehicle.getVehicleType()).process(vehicle);
```

What is the best way to do it using Spring framework?

Comment: what do you mean by more complex vehicle types?

Comment: @red I mean a custom POJO and not just predefined data type like String